# SPServices/JQuery How to Detect If The Current User Is System Accout

Tags: jquery, spservices

I need to detect if the current user is system account. With SPServices i can find user login name:

```
var thisUserName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
                        fieldName: "Title",
                        debug: false

                        });
```

But with system account logged in, this JS function gives the login name of the real user so i cannot define that the user is system account.

Comment: I'm not sure why this wouldn't work as well as any of the other posts below. Weren't you getting the system account name?

Comment: No the code block in my question post does not give system account, it only gives the login name of the real user.

Comment: That's exactly what the get_currentUser() functions below will give, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve required functionality using sharepoint javascript object model, try following code:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runMyCode, "SP.js");
function runMyCode() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    ctx.load(web);
    var user = web.get_currentUser();
    user.retrieve();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
                    //success function
            if(user.get_loginName() == "SHAREPOINT\\system"){
                alert(String.format("This is system account - {0}", user.get_loginName()));
            } else {
                alert(String.format("This is normal user - {0}", user.get_loginName()));
            }
        }, 
        function (data) {
            //notify the failure
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By this code you should able to get the "system\account" user:

```
   context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   web = context.get_web();
   var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
   alert(currentUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the SPServices library works, but if you need the user name/login to be displayed as "System Account" you can try this:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
theUser = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(this.theUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(.........);
```

After that theUser.get_title() should report "System Account", while theUser.get_loginName() should display "SHAREPOINT\system" (Note: I have left out the call back code for executeQueryAsync)

Can this be enough for you?